# SQL Access 2003 create column if exisit value

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2003

I've three table

```
    Product        
     - ID_Product

    UP
     - ID_Product
     - UP_SUM

    DOWN
     - ID_Product
     - DOWN_SUM
```

The query on this three tables create a column Total_SUM = [UP_SUM]-[DOWN_SUM]

The problem is that if there is no value in DOWN_SUM there is no result in Total_SUM.

EX.

```
    UP
    1 - 2
    2 - 4
    3 - 2

    DOWN 
    1 - 1
    3 - 1

    TOTAL_SUM
    (1) 1
    (2) 4 -> value missing
    (3) 1
```

In the fact i don't get the value for the ID 2.

How can i use statement if not isNULL to get all values in TOTAL_SUM? Actually the SQL Query is:

```sql
    SELECT 
    Product.ID_Product, 
    UP.UP_SUM, 
    DOWN.DOWN_SUM, 
    [UP_SUM]-[DOWN_SUM] AS TOTAL_SUM,

    FROM (PRODUCT INNER JOIN UP ON Product.ID_Product = UP.ID_Product)
    INNER JOIN DOWN ON Product.ID_Product = DOWN.ID_Product;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the iif condition that will replace null with a value, and use left outer join since normal join is filtering those rows without a match. A left join will keep them with the values NULL

IIF(ISNULL(DOWN.DOWN_SUM),0,DOWN.DOWN_SUM)

```
 SELECT 
    Product.ID_Product, 
    IIF(ISNULL(UP.UP_SUM),0,UP.UP_SUM), 
    IIF(ISNULL(DOWN.DOWN_SUM),0,DOWN.DOWN_SUM), 
    IIF(ISNULL(UP.UP_SUM),0,UP.UP_SUM)-IIF(ISNULL(DOWN.DOWN_SUM),0,DOWN.DOWN_SUM) AS TOTAL_SUM,
    FROM (PRODUCT LEFT OUTER JOIN UP ON Product.ID_Product = UP.ID_Product)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DOWN ON Product.ID_Product = DOWN.ID_Product;
```

Comment: same result, so frustrating @sagi

Comment: @CarloM_dtb Ohh, i found your problem, u used inner join instead of left join. Updated the answer. I think you can do it with your query with out the iif, but i'm not sure how ms access relates with summing nulls

Comment: Tnx a lot! It works. Yes, you're right, i need to study the case to find how ms-access works with null values